Lost at SQL Game: SQL Query to Identify Impostor Marine Species Returns Incorrect Result
I'm working on a SQL problem where I need to identify impostor marine species based on their attributes. The species I'm dealing with are clownfish, octopuses, and starfish. The attributes include species name, length (in meters), weight (in kilograms), and habitat type. I've written a query to determine if a species is an impostor based on specific criteria, but one of the 16 rows returned is incorrect.
Link to the problem
The error is: "You have the right columns and the right number of rows, but one of your 16 rows doesn't have the expected values."
The dataset has the following columns:

species_name (string): the name of the species
common_name (string): the common name of the species length
length (float): the length of the species in meters
weight (float): the weight of the species in
kilograms
habitat_type (string): the type of habitat the species is
found in (e.g. coral reef, rocky shore, kelp forest)

Data provided for averages:

Clownfish: 3-7 inches in length, 0.2-0.8 pounds in weight, habitat in coral reef
Octopuses: 12-36 inches in length, 6.6-23 pounds in weight, habitat in coastal marine waters
Starfish: 0.5-40 inches in length, 3.3-6.6 pounds in weight, habitat in kelp forest

The values in the dataset are in meters and kilograms, but ranges provided in inches and pounds, so I believe I need to convert the criteria ranges. Any help identifying the error or correcting the query would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a multitude of different queries and this is the closest I have gotten.
Attachments:
Initially, with correct logic and without converting values, the output was 7 of 16 incorrect rows. This was the code:
SELECT *,
       CASE 
           WHEN species_name = 'clownfish'
                AND length BETWEEN 3 AND 7
                AND weight BETWEEN 0.2 AND 0.8
                AND habitat_type = 'coral reef'
                THEN 'not impostor'
           WHEN species_name = 'octopus'
                AND length BETWEEN 12 AND 36
                AND weight BETWEEN 6.6 AND 23
                AND habitat_type = 'coastal marine waters'
                THEN 'not impostor'
           WHEN species_name = 'starfish'
                AND length BETWEEN 0.5 AND 40
                AND weight BETWEEN 3.3 AND 6.6
                AND habitat_type = 'kelp forest'
                THEN 'not impostor'
           ELSE 'impostor'
       END AS impostor_status
FROM marine_life;

I then proceeded to apply the conversions to the units, which returned 15 of 16 incorrect rows. Therefore, I reversed the logic, which returned 1 incorrect row. The following statement is the closest I have gotten, however I understand it is flawed.
SQL query:
SELECT *,
       CASE 
           WHEN species_name = 'clownfish'
                AND length BETWEEN 3 * 0.0254 AND 7 * 0.0254
                AND weight BETWEEN 0.2 * 0.453592 AND 0.8 * 0.453592
                AND habitat_type = 'coral reef'
                THEN 'impostor'
           WHEN species_name = 'octopus'
                AND length BETWEEN 12 * 0.0254 AND 36 * 0.0254
                AND weight BETWEEN 6.6 * 0.453592 AND 23 * 0.453592
                AND habitat_type = 'coastal marine waters'
                THEN 'impostor'
           WHEN species_name = 'starfish'
                AND length BETWEEN 0.5 * 0.0254 AND 40 * 0.0254
                AND weight BETWEEN 3.3 * 0.453592 AND 6.6 * 0.453592
                AND habitat_type = 'kelp forest'
                THEN 'impostor'
           ELSE 'not impostor'
       END AS impostor_status
FROM marine_life;

Screenshot of output:


Is that the original data set or your calcs?

Check your source data against the query, this is the only way to fix your problem.

The logic in the query looks flawed - why is an individual an impostor if it fits all the criteria for the species? Shouldn't it be considered an impostor if it doesn't fit the criteria?
This looks true for Carl - look at the length.

You're doing a select * but the length and weight seem to be already converted to in/lb?

@Nathan_Sav The original data for the averages is mentioned in the post:
Clownfish: 3-7 inches in length, 0.2-0.8 pounds in weight, habitat in coral reef
Octopuses: 12-36 inches in length, 6.6-23 pounds in weight, habitat in coastal marine waters
Starfish: 0.5-40 inches in length, 3.3-6.6 pounds in weight, habitat in kelp forest
I performed the conversions myself

@FrankSchmitt Correct, the logic is flawed. I've updated the question to reflect the process of how I got to that point.

@Dogbert Can you explain further? I don't understand how the select all has connection to the conversion.

@Jack the question says the length is in meters but the values in the screenshot seem to be in inches but you haven't converted the value in the column.

@Dogbert if I convert the values in the case statement, surely it doesn't matter whether the values are converted in the column?
